# Windows Batch script - For /L not working -- simple

Tags: windows, batch-file, variable-assignment

need some quick help. This is a university program, everything is working fine except when I call my :forLoop method to iterate through 100 numbers (1,1,100)  starting at 1 going by 1 til 100 and doing the iteration % 5 (i%%5). for some reason I cannot get this to work. appreciate any help or direction.

When I echo %%A it is iterating through all the number perfect. When I echo %result% I get a blank "" (nothing inside)

```
:forLoop
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,100) DO (
set /A result=%%A %% 2
echo "%%A"
echo "%result%"
)
```

Correct code is

```
:forLoop
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,100) DO (
set /A result=%%A %% 5
echo !result! >> results.txt
set /A total=!total!+!result!
echo !total!
)
```

Comment: Got it. (I was checking the docs on `set`.) :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Apparently I should have done the same!!!! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `%result%` is substituted when the `for` is read, meaning that it is no longer a variable when the loop is executed. What you need is *delayed variable expansion* to be enabled and then use `!` instead of `%`:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:forLoop
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,100) DO (
set /A result=%%A %% 5
echo "%%A"
echo !result!
)
```

This is all explained in the help message you get when you run `SET /?`:

```
Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around
the limitations of the current expansion which happens when a line
of text is read, not when it is executed.  The following example
demonstrates the problem with immediate variable expansion:

    set VAR=before
    if "%VAR%" == "before" (
        set VAR=after
        if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
    )

would never display the message, since the %VAR% in BOTH IF statements
is substituted when the first IF statement is read, since it logically
includes the body of the IF, which is a compound statement.  So the
IF inside the compound statement is really comparing "before" with
"after" which will never be equal.  Similarly, the following example
will not work as expected:

    set LIST=
    for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
    echo %LIST%

in that it will NOT build up a list of files in the current directory,
but instead will just set the LIST variable to the last file found.
Again, this is because the %LIST% is expanded just once when the
FOR statement is read, and at that time the LIST variable is empty.
So the actual FOR loop we are executing is:

    for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i

which just keeps setting LIST to the last file found.

Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different
character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at
execution time.  If delayed variable expansion is enabled, the above
examples could be written as follows to work as intended:

    set VAR=before
    if "%VAR%" == "before" (
        set VAR=after
        if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
    )

    set LIST=
    for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
    echo %LIST%
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `!result!` as the output of the second `echo`.